# Prove the universal class = the empty class??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to set theory and am reading Pinter's Introduction to Set Theory.  The universal class is defined as the class of all elements.  The empty class is defined as the class which has no elements.  Then, in the Algebra of Classes, Theorem 1.26v states: For every class A, the universal class = the empty class. The reader is invited to prove this as an exercise.  I don't understand how this could possibly be true, much less how to prove it.  The axiom of extent says that two classes are equal iff an element belonging to one class implies that it also belongs to the other class and vice versa.  I am very confused!!

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: If so, then the universe is empty. But something exists ($\emptyset$ itself, in fact). Contradiction.

Comment: I don´t understand what is the question.

Comment: This is the statement one is supposed to prove:  For every class A, $$U=\emptyset$$.

Comment: I would add that $$U$$ is defined as the class of all elements (not a set of all sets which would lead to Russell's paradox).  Similarly $$\emptyset$$ is  class which has no elements at all.

Answer (score 5):

I have a copy of the book, and you simply misread the problem.  It's asking you to prove that ${\mathscr{U}}^{'}=\emptyset$.  That is, show that the *complement* of the universal class is empty. So your intuition is sound in that the problem as you had read it did not make sense.

Comment: I have the Kindle version of the book and even when I enlarged the print as much as possible there is no apostrophe mark with the U.  So I guess it's a defect in that version.  Thank you so much for your reply because this was really worrying me...I was thinking I should just give up trying to read about set theory if I couldn't understand such a basic idea!!!

Comment: For what it's worth, I looked on Google Books and found that while the Addison-Wesley version of Pinter's Set Theory (which I own a print copy of) has the apostrophe, the Dover edition does not (same exercise (1.26v), slightly different book title).

Comment: I was stuck as well. It was just a typo.